# Credit Card Payment Error: invalid parameter were supplied to stripe API

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Basically its a form created with WPForm plugin in WordPress

[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRR26.png)

this is the main error .
plz help me solve this

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this you would need to look at the exact request/response to the API, which may require access to the backend used to create parts of the payment flow.

You should reach out to the [WPForms support team](https://wpforms.com/account/support/) for help with your use of their plugin.